# BroadcastReceiver onReceive timeout

Tags: android, timeout, broadcastreceiver

I extend `BroadcastReceiver`, and in `onReceive()` I do whatever I need to do.

`onReceive()` has a timeout, from the documentation:

> there is a timeout of 10 seconds that
>   the system allows before considering
>   the receiver to be blocked and a
>   candidate to be killed

This creates a problem when I am in debug mode. I need more than 10 seconds (sometimes). If I don't do all my debugging in 10 seconds my connection is closed and debugging is stopped.

Can I increase the timeout or disable it for debugging purposes?

Thanks.

Comment: If you're doing stuff that takes more than even a fraction of a second in your broadcast receiver, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Read my comment below. I am talking about DEBUG mode.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to prevent your app from force closing while you are paused on a break point during debugging, try installing the **Dev Tools application** and enable the **Debug App** setting which:

> Lets you select the application to
>   debug. You do not need to set this to
>   attach a debugger, but setting this
>   value has two effects:
>
> - It will prevent Android from throwing an error if you pause on a
>     breakpoint for a long time while
>     debugging.

All of the details are here: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-devtools.html

If you are doing something complicated in your `onReceive` method, then consider having your `BroadcastReceiver` start a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) and pass along the data it gets from within `onReceive`. The `Service` can then do the longer processing.

Comment: This is correct. The SOLE purpose of a broadcast receiver should be to pass data on to something else.

Comment: Guys, I agree with you. You are right. In a Release version it shouldn't take that long at all. But I am talking in DEBUG mode, when I am debugging through my code.

Comment: It doesn't matter that you're in "DEBUG" mode. You still want to have the receiver pass off to another component immediately, probably a Service as elevine recommended. That is the correct design and it will be easier to debug and troubleshoot as well as not causing receiver timeouts (do your logging, or whatever it is that is taking longer? in the Service).

Comment: Do you mean that you set a break point within your onReceive method, and while you are paused the application force quits?

Comment: @elevine yes, exactly. Sorry I didn't make it clear enough in the question.

Comment: @Alexandru Luchian  I have edited my original answer to better address this.

Comment: Where exactly is this Dev Tools Application? I have  similar problem in the onReceive method of my home screen widget I get WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xf3c30c00,peer=0x12c0a0a0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3 after less than one second

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem even when in debug mode.  It turns out that another broadcast was being sent and wasn't being handled because I was debugging the other broadcast on the main thread.  Android considered my process to be in ANR and killed the whole process.

I had to temporarily modify the code to not call the other broadcast while doing my debugging.

Comment: How exaclty did you modify it? I am having the same problem.

Comment: @Para, I commented out the code that sent broadcasts in the section I was debugging starting with the break point.