# Debugger gets disconnected during debug when Broadcastreceiver timeout occurs

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager

I am writing an app on simulator in eclipse with adb/android tools etc.
While I am debugging my broadcastreceiver code below, in a certain section of the code the debugger gets detached while I stay there for few seconds..

It does not give me enough time to debug and disconnects,

errors are like

> - 03-01 20:42:38.293: I/CallListener(320): onReceive.. 03-01    20:42:48.319: W/ActivityManager(59): Timeout of broadcast
>     BroadcastRecord{45098250 android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE} -
>     receiver=android.os.BinderProxy@450d2070 03-01 20:42:48.319:
>     W/ActivityManager(59): Receiver during timeout: ResolveInfo{45032058
>     mahmed.net.apps.CallListener p=0 o=0 m=0x108000} 03-01 20:42:48.353:
>     I/Process(59): Sending signal. PID: 320 SIG: 3 03-01 20:42:48.353:
>     I/dalvikvm(320): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3 03-01 20:42:48.353: 
>     I/dalvikvm(320): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt' 03-01
>     20:42:48.362: I/Process(59): Sending signal. PID: 59 SIG: 3 03-01
>     20:42:48.362: I/dalvikvm(59): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3

The section where the debugger gets disconnected is

```
if (newCallState.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK))
{
    Utils.log(TAG, "off hook...");
    // Do necessary work to start off a service etc ..
    // If I debug here for few seconds the debugger gets detached.. without any errors 
}
```

The full code of broadcastreceiver is like this:

```
public class CallListener extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    Context m_context;  
    /**
     * Called on application thread
     */

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        Utils.log(TAG, "onReceive..");
        m_context = context;
        String strAction = intent.getAction();

        Assert.assertNotNull(strAction);
        if(strAction.equals(android.telephony.TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED))
        {
            handleCallStateChanged(context, intent);
        }       
    }


    private void handleCallStateChanged(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Utils.log(TAG, "handling call state changed");
        String newCallState = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

        if (newCallState.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK))
        {
             Utils.log(TAG, "off hook...");
             // Do necessary work to start off a service etc ..
             // If I debug here for few seconds the debugger gets detached.. without any errors 
        }
    }
}
```

more in

Answer (score 2):

There was a thread with the same issue:
[BroadcastReceiver onReceive timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650016/broadcastreceiver-onreceive-timeout)

Copy/Paste

> In order to prevent your app from force closing while you are paused
>   on a break point during debugging, try installing the Dev Tools
>   application and enable the Debug App setting which:
>
> > Lets you select the application to debug. You do not need to set this
> >     to attach a debugger, but setting this value has two effects:
> >
> > It will prevent Android from throwing an error if you pause on a
> >     breakpoint for a long time while debugging.
>
> All of the details are here:
>   <strike>http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debug-tasks.html#additionaldebugging</strike>
>
> If you are doing something complicated in your onReceive method, then
>   consider having your BroadcastReceiver start a Service and pass along
>   the data it gets from within onReceive. The Service can then do the
>   longer processing.

The link to the developer doc from google was broken
Here you have it:
http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-devtools.html

Comment: I've read this solution before and it has no effect. My debugger detaches with : W/BroadcastQueue(  493): Timeout of broadcast BroadcastRecord{52c4a2c8 u-1 android.intent.action.TIME_TICK} - receiver=android.os.BinderProxy@52c1f308, started 10000ms ago

Comment: @JohnTwigg in your log you can see the "10000ms ago", which means this timeout. You need to (have to) run a service just on receive the event. Not doing the work on the onReceive.