# Extend timeout when debugging xamarin android apps with visual studio

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, adb, visual-studio-debugging

Debugging a Xamarin forms app on a physical android device from Visual Studio 2022, which works fine. If, however, I need to think just a little more while debugging on a breakpoint, the app closes and debugging stops. Likely because the app was unresponsive and android killed it.

There seems to be options to change adb timeout for android studio, but I have seen absolutely no mention of the issue outside those references. Is there some obscure android setting, or how do you manage to get more than a few seconds to consider what you are actually seeing when debugging?

Comment: This answer to a similar question should point you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4650084/769265

Comment: What device do you use for debugging? Xamarin based apps are to my experience pretty resource hungry (CPOU and RAM) so may be the device is just too weak?

Comment: @DavidWasser from what I understand this is again related to android studio and not something I can use with my setup.

Comment: @Robert that certainly rings true, but it is a somewhat modern android phone that has no issues running the app, and just bails on pausing a few seconds too long on breakpoints.

Comment: This is the android system's default behavior, when the app didn't response after 5 seconds, the system will ask user to kill the process.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I realize that. The question is how to disable this when debugging, as often five seconds is not long enough.

Comment: This is system's behavior, you can't achieve that.